# Export Nodes to RSS or CSV

Tags: views, importing-exporting, feeds

I need to export blog entries from Drupal to a XML RSS feed or a CSV file. I have spent countless hours trying to export it, however, no results whatsoever. I have created a new view based on the defaults of the Blog node and have set the following parameters:

- Style: RSS Feed
- Row style: node
- Items to display: 25
- Path: latestblogs/feed
- Attach to: Blog page

The feed page does work, however, none of the entries are appearing. What do you think is the issue?

[image: RSS settings]

Comment: Can you post pictures of your view configuration? Is this Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: @Kevin I believe this is version 6. Let me add the screenshot.

Comment: Drupal 6? Now that's a name I haven't heard in a loonnng time. http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/4/4e/ObiWanHS-SWE.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/500?cb=20111115052816

Comment: Interesting.... I don't necessarily see anything wrong in the view config here. Is the RSS page just totally blank, as in no underlying markup? Are there any server errors or logs?

Comment: @Kevin it's just completely blank.

Comment: Interesting.... sounds like an error. It has been forever since I have used 6.x though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export a View as XML or CSV, you will want [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export).

Edit: now that I know this is for Drupal 6, you will have to dig to find the releases for 6.x on the project page. [Here they are](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export/releases?api_version%5B%5D=87).

Comment: Thanks for that! I have tried most of the latest beta releases for version 6, however, they're not listing in the Modules page.

Comment: It doesn't appear in the list of modules whatsoever? That's odd. I do recall using it in 6.x for report exporting.

Comment: Nope. I have "views exporter" though. I am guessing that's different, right?

Comment: It should definitely say Views Data Export, as that is what is listed in the module info file

Comment: Strange. I'll try an earlier release.

Comment: Do i need to run the update.php file?